# glsl specular not working

Tags: glsl

ok, i'm a complete noob regarding shaders and all this, so i must be doing something really stupid, but i cannot get specular lighting to work.
I've read a whole lot of different shaders on the internet, and there are a whole lot of different ones, with different uniforms.

This is what i have...

Vertex shader

```
#version 300 es

in vec3 VertexPosition;
in vec3 VertexNormal;
in vec2 TexCoord;

struct SInputUniforms
    {
    mat4 ViewMatrix;
    mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
    mat4 ModelWorldMatrix;
    vec3 CameraPosition;
    };

struct SVertexToFrag
    {
    vec3 WorldFragPosition;
    vec3 WorldVertexNormal;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    };

uniform SInputUniforms InputUniforms;
out SVertexToFrag VertexToFrag;

void main()
    {
    gl_Position = InputUniforms.ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
    VertexToFrag.TexCoord = TexCoord;
    VertexToFrag.WorldFragPosition = (InputUniforms.ModelWorldMatrix * vec4 (VertexPosition,1.0f)).xyz;
    VertexToFrag.WorldVertexNormal = (InputUniforms.ModelWorldMatrix * vec4 (VertexNormal,0.0f)).xyz;
    }
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

struct SMaterial
    {
    vec4 Diffuse, Ambient, Specular;
    float Shininess;
    };

struct SFragInputUniforms
    {
    sampler2D TextureSampler;
    };

uniform SFragInputUniforms FragInputUniforms;

uniform SMaterial Material;
uniform vec3 CameraPositionWorld;

struct SVertexToFrag
    {
    vec3 WorldFragPosition;
    vec3 WorldVertexNormal;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    };

in SVertexToFrag VertexToFrag;

out vec4 FragColor;

//#if LIGHTING_ENABLED==1

// Light data
struct SPointLight
    {
    vec3 Color;
    vec3 Position;
    float Intensity;
    float ConstantAttenuation;
    float LinearAttenuation;
    float ExponentialAttenuation;
    float Cutoff;
    };

struct SAmbientLight
    {
    vec3 Color;
    float Intensity;
    };

struct SInputLightData
    {
    int PointLightCount;
    SPointLight PointLights[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
    SAmbientLight AmbientLight;
    };
uniform SInputLightData InputLightData;

vec3 CalculateLights ( void )
    {
    vec3 OverallResult = (InputLightData.AmbientLight.Color * InputLightData.AmbientLight.Intensity * Material.Ambient.xyz );
    vec3 SurfaceToCamera = VertexToFrag.WorldFragPosition - CameraPositionWorld;

// Apply point lights
    for ( int LightIndex = 0; LightIndex < InputLightData.PointLightCount; ++LightIndex )
        {
        vec3 LightResult = vec3 ( 0, 0, 0 );
        vec3 SurfaceToLight = InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].Position - VertexToFrag.WorldFragPosition;

        float Distance = length ( SurfaceToLight );
        if ( Distance > InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].Cutoff )
            continue;

        // Calculate normalized vectors and Lambert term
        vec3 NormalizedFragVertexNormalWorld = normalize( VertexToFrag.WorldVertexNormal );
        vec3 NormalizedSurfaceToLight = normalize( SurfaceToLight );
        float LambertTerm = max( dot( NormalizedSurfaceToLight, NormalizedFragVertexNormalWorld ), 0 ); // Should I use normalized here?

        // Compute the diffuse term.
        vec3 DiffuseResult = LambertTerm * InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].Intensity * InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].Color * Material.Diffuse.xyz;
        LightResult += DiffuseResult;

        // Compute specular
    //  float SpecularCoefficient = 0.0;
    //  if ( LambertTerm > 0.0 )
    //      SpecularCoefficient = pow ( max ( 0.0, dot ( SurfaceToCamera, reflect(-SurfaceToLight, NormalizedFragVertexNormalWorld))), Material.Shininess);
    //  vec3 SpecularResult = SpecularCoefficient * Material.Specular.xyz * InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].Color;
    //  LightResult += SpecularResult;

        // Compute attenuation
        float Attenuation = InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].ConstantAttenuation + InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].LinearAttenuation * Distance + InputLightData.PointLights[LightIndex].ExponentialAttenuation * pow ( Distance, 2 );

        LightResult /= Attenuation;
        OverallResult += LightResult;
        }

    return OverallResult;
    } 
// #endif

void main()
    {
    vec4 OverallFragColor;    
    OverallFragColor = Material.Diffuse;

#if LIGHTING_ENABLED==1
    OverallFragColor *= vec4 ( CalculateLights(), 1.0f );
#endif

    FragColor = OverallFragColor;
    }
```

Most probably, the problem is not in the shaders, but in the uniform's values.
I populate ViewMatrix with the camera translation matrix ( translation * rotation ), ModelWorldMatrix with the same thing for the model being drawn.

with diffuse:
[image]

with diffuse + specular:
[image]